# JQuery detect arrow down keypress

Tags: jquery

I'm facing an issue which I can't seem to solve.
I have a function which loads search results when an user starts typing. On enter, the first result is chosen.

Now what I'm trying is to detect the arrow down key, so I can select the next search result.

```
   $(document).on('input propertychange', '#customer', function (event) {
        searchCustomer(this.value);

        delay(function () {
            $('#search_results').children().first().toggleClass('fancy-border');
        }, 100);
    });

    $(document).on('input propertychange', '#product', function () {
        searchProduct(this.value);
    });

    $(document).on('input keypress', '#customer,#product', function (event) {

        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 40:
                console.log('down');
                $('#search_results').find('.fancy-border').removeClass('fancy-border').next('.customer-item').toggleClass('fancy-border');
                break;
            case 39:
                console.log('right');
                break;
            case 37:
                console.log('left');
                break;
            case 13:
                console.log('enter');
//                $('#search_results').find('.fancy-border').trigger('click');
                break;
        }
    });
```

The enter works perfectly fine, and also logs, but the arrows aren't working, none of them.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

I tried to create a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/28da2u6r/2/

Comment: Have you tried `.keydown(...)` instead of `.on(..)`?

Comment: I added a JSFiddle, when I do on keydown, it doesn't ever select my item.

Comment: I've tested your fiddle and it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/28da2u6r/3/ , also, the code of your fiddle doesn't match the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.keydown(...)` instead of `.on(...)`:

```
$(document).keydown('.test', function (event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 40:
            console.log('down');
            break;
        case 39:
            console.log('right');
            break;
        case 37:
            console.log('left');
            break;
        case 13:
            console.log('enter');
            break;
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asjqt4p5/2/)